# check if the url is a hash link in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello i have following code, and i know this must be very simple but i cant figure out the issue.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").click(function() { 
        $('#loader').show(); 
    }); });
```

The code above works perfect
what i want now is to show the #loader only if the link is not a hash link.

i tried this but dosent works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").click(function() { 
        if (window.location.hash ) {
        $('#theloader_90').show(); 
            }
    }); });
```

any help is appreciated. Thankx

Comment: `if (!window.location.hash ) {
        $('#theloader_90').show(); 
 }`

Comment: tried that too, dosent works.

Comment: Do you mean if the _link that you're clicking_ has a hash? If so you'll want to check it's `href` using `.attr("href")`.